# Pro-Tempore Moderator Nominations

Tags: discussion, moderators

Well, we've been a week into Private Beta. According to the [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), the SE Team will pick up (usually 3) users to become Moderators more or less a week into Public Beta, until we graduate, so let's start with nominations. After graduation there will be actual elections where users can nominate and actually vote.

*Read carefully.*

### But what does it take to be a Moderator?

According to the blog post above, Moderator should:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

### Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

### Some notes

- You can self-nominate or nominate others. Each nomination should be posted as a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so everyone can see their activity. Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.
- If the nomination was posted by a 3rd-party, the nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.

Answer (score 17):

**[Krazer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/63/krazer)**, [meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/63/krazer)

I know this user from the Chinese SE, where I'm a moderator. I'm proposing him, because I already know him, more or less, and he strikes me as a nice, laid-back person.

He's the current top-reputation user, he's quite a prolific editor, too.

> "I accept, because @Alenanno is such a cool dude," Krazer replied in a relaxed tone.

Answer (score 12):

I nominate [Alenanno](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/15/alenanno), [meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15/alenanno).

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active,
  consistent participation.  **Yep**
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities. **It seems like that**
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write. **I think so**
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.  **I think so**

Plus, it looks like he was mod before:

> Appointed ♦ Moderator Pro Tempore on Linguistics SE, Chinese SE and the Russian SE site

---

Thanks for the nomination. Before the Nominations started I said that since I already was (am) a mod on three sites, I would leave the others first and that I would only step up if I was needed (i.e. a third name was needed). I still think so.

I greatly appreciate the trust and I think I'll like spending time on this site and its community. I don't hide I'd like to help actively being a mod, nevertheless, leaving others trying this experience is the right thing to do (I even nominated two other users). Ultimately the Team will decide and they probably know better, but I had to say this again.

In any case, I accept the nomination, if my participation will be deemed necessary.

Comment: I want to upvote this :I

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to nominate myself, **[Madara Uchiha](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/27/madara-uchiha)**, [meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/27/madara-uchiha).

1. I'm active on both the main site, and meta. I see great potential in this site, and would like to help it grow.
2. 36k reputation over on Stack Overflow, I know the Stack Exchange system and mentality well.
3. I'd love to help anyone in need. I'm already dealing with flags on Stack Overflow, and would love to do the same here.

Good luck to all nominees!

Answer (score 10):

I'll nominate myself, [JNat](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/49/jnat), [meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/49/jnat).

- I am rather new at the SE community, but **I think I can help this site grow and live up to its potential**.
- Although this is currently the SE site where I have my highest rep, **I am among the top users rep-wise and activity-wise**.

Good luck to all! :D

Answer (score 8):

**[SingerOfTheFall](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/111/singerofthefall)**, [meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/111/singerofthefall)

This user is active on SO and so knows the rules pretty well.

I've seen him intervening on many Meta questions with common sense, well-organized thoughts and it seemed to me that he had clear ideas on how to organize things.

---

Thank you for nominating me, I gladly accept the nomination (and yes, I'm a man, not a woman;). I've been using StackExchange for about half a year in total, mostly using StackOverflow (and reading the meta often), so I know about how the system works, and what is the community role in it.

I also enjoy both helping people (by answering their questions as best as I can and helping them to improve their posts) and looking after the site by doing review tasks.

Good luck to all participants, and let the best nominees be appointed.